# Work on current children of a table row instead of all elements of name or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help limiting a jQuery function to a certain table row instead of working on all elements of a class/name. I could use IDs here, if I knew how to get an unique ID of a  after it was added. Since I would have to create the ID unique each time I add a field, I don't think that this would be an easy and elegant way. So I am looking for how use find() the right way to get the exact parent  of the child input field I worked on or a different, maybe more sophisticated way of selecting the parent.

With the help of other questions asked here, I have created the following code:
A table in a form that looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr class="service_list">
        <td><a href="#" onclick="add_row();">+</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The function "add_row()" that adds a row to the table

```
function add_row()
{
    $('table tr.service_list:last').after('<tr>\
        <td>\
            <select class="profile service" name="service_list[]">\
                <option value="50">service50</option>\
                <option value="100">service100</option>\
            </select>\
        </td>\
        <td>\
            <input type="text" name="rate[]" value="1" />\
        </td>\
        <td>\
            <input type="text" name="single_price[]" value="50" \>\
        </td>\
        <td>\
            <input type="text" name="total[]" value="50" />\
        </td>\
    </tr>');
}
```

When the user changes the select field, thanks to the "attributeStartsWith" selector this jQuery is triggered

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    var value = $('select[name^=service_list]').val();
    var rate = $('input[name^=rate]').val();
    var total = value*rate;    
    $('[name^=single_price]').val(value);
    $('input[name^=total]').val(total)
});
```

And when the "rate" field is changed, this will be triggered calculating the total price

```
$(document).on('input', '[name^=rate]', function(e) {
    var rate = $('input[name^=rate]').val();
    var orig_price = $('[name^=single_price]').val();

    var total = orig_price * rate;

    $('[name^=total]').val(total);
});
```

Of course as it is now, the value of all fields name starting "total" gets changed. Same would happen, if I used classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery DOM traversal methods to find the elements you want within the same `tr` as the element which raised the event. In this case, you can use `closest()` and `find()`, like this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var value = $row.find('select[name^=service_list]').val();
    var rate = $row.find('input[name^=rate]').val();
    var total = value * rate;    
    $row.find('[name^=single_price]').val(value);
    $row.find('input[name^=total]').val(total)
});

$(document).on('input', '[name^=rate]', function(e) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rate = $row.find('input[name^=rate]').val();
    var orig_price = $row.find('[name^=single_price]').val();    
    var total = orig_price * rate;    
    $row.find('[name^=total]').val(total);
});
```

Note that you may see better performance from your code by using classes over the 'attribute begins with' selector.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Also thanks for the class hint I will use that in my code for clarity.